# Change the Event name while creating S3 event notification trigger in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I was able to create a S3 upload trigger via CDK

But the event-name is some random alphanumeric string

Is there any way I can define this event-trigger name

Code snippet of CDK code

```
        const sqs = Queue.fromQueueArn(this,"sqs",
        mySQS.sqsARN);

    this.s3bucket.addObjectCreatedNotification(new SqsDestination(sqs))
```

The trigger event screenshot

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: There is not a property for it in SqsDestination object - however, if you set the name of the queue itself you could see if that will affect the naming schema of the event notifiactions?